# How to build a Map that replicates a Function in Java's Lambda API

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, enum-map

From a `java.util.function.BiFunction` that maps a pair of `Enum`s  into a value, I want to build a `EnumMap` that reflects that mapping.

For instance, let `E1` and `E2` be `enum` types and `T` any given type:

```
 BiFunction<E1,E2, T> theBiFunction = //...anything

 EnumMap<E1,EnumMap<E2,T>> theMap = 
    buildTheMap(                     // <--  this is where the magic happens
                E1.values(), 
                E2.values(),
                theBiFunction);
```

Given any pair of values of type `E1` and `E2`

```
E1 e1 = //any valid value...
E2 e2 = //any valid value....
```

both values below should be equal:

```
T valueFromTheMaps = theMap.get(e1).get(e2);
T valueFromTheFunction = theBiFunction.apply(e1,e2);

boolean alwaysTrue = valueFromTheMaps.equals(valueFromTheFunction);
```

What's the best (more elegant, efficient, etc...) implementation for the method where the "*magic*" takes place?

Comment: What does your inelegant, inefficient version look like?

Comment: Two nested forEachs adding stuff to the map. :(

Comment: ... and what's wrong with that?

Comment: See @stuart-marks's answer below, for instance, to understand how the issue could be addressed under different approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get an elegant solution if you go to a generic solution and break it down. First, implement a generic function which creates an `EnumMap` out of a `Function`, then implement the nested mapping of a `BiFunction` using the first function combined with itself:

```
static <T,E extends Enum<E>>
  EnumMap<E,T> funcToMap(Function<E,T> f, Class<E> t, E... values) {
    return Stream.of(values)
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), f, (x,y)->x, ()-> new EnumMap<>(t)));
}
static <T,E1 extends Enum<E1>,E2 extends Enum<E2>>
  EnumMap<E1,EnumMap<E2,T>> biFuncToMap(
  BiFunction<E1,E2,T> f, Class<E1> t1, Class<E2> t2, E1[] values1, E2[] values2){

  return funcToMap(e1->funcToMap(e2->f.apply(e1, e2), t2, values2), t1, values1);
}
```

---

Here’s a little test case:

```
enum Fruit {
    APPLE, PEAR
}
enum Color {
    RED, GREED, YELLOW
}
```

…

```
EnumMap<Fruit, EnumMap<Color, String>> result
  =biFuncToMap((a,b)->b+" "+a,
     Fruit.class, Color.class, Fruit.values(), Color.values());
System.out.println(result);
```

→

```
{APPLE={RED=RED APPLE, GREED=GREED APPLE, YELLOW=YELLOW APPLE}, PEAR={RED=RED PEAR, GREED=GREED PEAR, YELLOW=YELLOW PEAR}}
```

Of course, using the generic solution you can built methods for concrete `enum` types which do not require the `Class` parameter(s)…

---

This ought to work smoothly with a parallel stream if the provided `(Bi)Function` is thread safe.

Comment: Very "elegant". If you allow me, it could be improved by removing the last parameter of funcToMap (`E... values`)  and using `E[] values = E.getEnumConstants()` in the method body.

Comment: @bruno: Actually you have passed the `enum` values into the factory method right in your question so I assumed that is was a requirement to be able to control the keys which are present in the `Map` via a parameter. If you want to have all constants I recommend adding another method delegating to this one using `getEnumConstants()`. This avoids calling `getEnumConstants()` multiple times in the nested usage. Btw. I didn’t forget `Collectors.`, I just assumed you will use a `static import`.

Comment: Oh, I've forgot about `static imports`.

Answer (score 2):

As a baseline for comparison, here's the conventional version:

```
<T> EnumMap<E1,EnumMap<E2,T>> buildTheMap(E1[] e1values,
                                          E2[] e2values,
                                          BiFunction<E1,E2,T> f) {
    EnumMap<E1,EnumMap<E2,T>> outer = new EnumMap<>(E1.class);
    for (E1 e1 : e1values) {
        EnumMap<E2,T> inner = new EnumMap<>(E2.class);
        for (E2 e2 : e2values) {
            inner.put(e2, f.apply(e1, e2));
        }
        outer.put(e1, inner);
    }
    return outer;
}
```

Now here's a version that uses nested three-arg forms of the `collect()` stream terminal operation:

```
<T> EnumMap<E1,EnumMap<E2,T>> buildTheMap(E1[] e1values,
                                          E2[] e2values,
                                          BiFunction<E1,E2,T> f) {
    return
        Stream.of(e1values)
              .collect(() -> new EnumMap<>(E1.class),
                       (map, e1) -> map.put(e1, Stream.of(e2values)
                                                      .collect(() -> new EnumMap<>(E2.class),
                                                               (m, e2) -> m.put(e2, f.apply(e1, e2)),
                                                               Map::putAll)),
                       Map::putAll);
}
```

What makes this cumbersome is that the accumulator function for the outer collector has to run a stream with its own three-arg collector to produce the inner map. This is really hard to indent well. Instead of standard spacing, I've lined up the three arguments to each `collect()` call. This makes it pretty wide, but if I didn't do this, it would be hard to see what goes with what since the nesting is so deep. As much of a fan of streams as I am, it's hard for me to say that this is any better than the conventional version.

You might say, "Why not use `toMap()` instead of the three-arg `collect()` function?" The problem is that we need to create `EnumMap` instances, and the overload of `toMap()` that takes a map supplier has *four* arguments:

```
toMap(keyFunc, valueFunc, mergeFunc, mapSupplier)
```

Worse, the merge function (third arg) isn't used, so we'd have to supply a function that's never used. Here's what that looks like:

```
<T> EnumMap<E1,EnumMap<E2,T>> buildTheMap(E1[] e1values,
                                          E2[] e2values,
                                          BiFunction<E1,E2,T> f) {
    return
        Stream.of(e1values)
              .collect(toMap(e1 -> e1,
                             e1 -> Stream.of(e2values)
                                         .collect(toMap(e2 -> e2,
                                                        e2 -> f.apply(e1, e2),
                                                        (x, y) -> x,
                                                        () -> new EnumMap<>(E2.class))),
                             (x, y) -> x,
                             () -> new EnumMap<>(E1.class)));
}
```

Doesn't look any better to me. My money is still on the conventional version.

There are a number of alternative approaches one could try. We'll see what a good night's sleep brings.

Comment: By focusing on all the lambdas you forgot about the good old way to make complex code simpler: by splitting it into multiple methods. [It could be two methods being (well almost) one-liners…](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25065237/2711488)

Comment: @Holger Well I didn't *forget*, it's just that it wasn't clear to me that it would actually improve things. And I was getting sleepy. :-) But thanks for your contribution (+1). In general I do agree that extracting little methods is a good technique. Unfortunately there's a certain amount of clumsiness collecting streams into maps to begin with. Additionally the question wants nested map, combined with the need to construct an `EnumMap` make things even worse. I still think there are simpler solutions struggling to get out. Especially if we are willing to consider API changes.

Comment: Isn’t it too late for API changes?

Comment: @Holger For Java 8, yes it is too late. But there is Java 9. It might seem early to think about this, but now that people are trying stuff out in Java 8, finding out what *doesn't* work well can be used to drive API changes (compatible of course) into Java 9.