# Why does this code fail to compile, citing type inference as the cause?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, javac, type-inference

Here's a minimal example of the code I'm working with:

```
public class Temp {
    enum SomeEnum {}

    private static final Map<SomeEnum, String> TEST = new EnumMap<>(
               Arrays.stream(SomeEnum.values())
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t, a -> "")));

}
```

The compiler output is:

```
Temp.java:27: error: cannot infer type arguments for EnumMap<>
    private static final Map<SomeEnum, String> TEST = new EnumMap<>(Arrays.stream(SomeEnum.values())
                                                      ^
```

I have found that this can be worked around by replacing `t -> t` with `Function.identity()` or `(SomeEnum t) -> t`, but I'm not understanding why this is the case. What limitation in javac is causing this behavior?

I originally found this issue with java 8, but have verified it still occurs with the java 11 compiler.

Comment: Make sure you test with javac, not the eclipse compiler. Eclipse compiler compiles this just fine.

Comment: Doesn't compile for me in both Intellij and with javac, both using Java 11.0.2

Comment: Intellij using java 1.8 intially displays the code as fine, but when actually compiling and running with javac this breaks during compile.

Comment: Moving to comments, what also fixes this is specifying the `Supplier` explicitly `new EnumMap<>(
            Arrays.stream(SomeEnum.values())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t, 
                            a -> "", (x, y) -> x, () -> new EnumMap<>(SomeEnum.class))));`. References from [Holger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25065237/1746118)

Comment: There are many workarounds, I listed a few. Function.identity() is probably the simplest, and even cleaner than the original code. However my question is *why* this happens. I'm aware it's possible to avoid the issue.

Comment: Again from Holger and possibly [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041480/1746118) linked with further detailed answers for a great explanation.

Comment: works fine with Java8 in eclipse IDE.

Comment: Have you seen the first comment? `Make sure you test with javac, not the eclipse compiler. Eclipse compiler compiles this just fine.`

Comment: Such type inference errors are not uncommon when I code. I have given up (for now at least) on understanding precisely how far Java’s type inference goes and when it needs help (read `(SomeEnum t) -> t`). I give it the help it requires and all is well.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question is deemed useful (entertaining _maybe_, but useful)? Even if someone comes along and meticulously writes up the JLS justification for this type inference limitation, what is anyone going to be able to do with this specific occurrence?

Comment: @Savior there are actually a bunch of people that like that, like seriously like. this isn't a place just for "useful"

Comment: this certainly looks like a bug to me, because if you change to `HashMap<>(....` it will work

Comment: @Eugene `EnumMap(Map<K, ? extends V> m)` compared to `HashMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m)`.. could the key type be the issue?

Comment: If we explicitly mention type instead of diamond operator then it compiles successfully i.e. private static final Map<SomeEnum, String> TEST = new EnumMap<SomeEnum, String>(...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can simplify the example further:

Declaring a method like

```
static <K,V> Map<K,V> test(Map<K,? extends V> m) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}
```

the statement

```
Map<SomeEnum, String> m = test(Collections.emptyMap());
```

can be compiled without problems. Now, when we change the method declaration to

```
static <K extends Enum<K>,V> Map<K,V> test(Map<K,? extends V> m) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}
```

we get a compiler error. This indicates that the difference between wrapping your stream expression with `new EnumMap<>(…)` and `new HashMap<>(…)` lies in the type parameter declaration of the key type, as `EnumMap`’s key type parameter has been declared as `K extends Enum<K>`.

It seems to be connected with the self-referential nature of the declaration, e.g. `K extends Serializable` does not cause an error while `K extends Comparable<K>` does.

While this fails in all `javac` versions from Java 8 to Java 11, the behavior is not as consistent as it seems. When we change the declaration to

```
static <K extends Enum<K>,V> Map<K,V> test(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}
```

the code can be compiled again under Java 8, but still fails with Java 9 to 11.

To me, it’s illogical that the compiler infers `SomeEnum` for `K` (which would match the bound `Enum<K>`) and `String` for `V`, but fails to infer these types when a bound has been specified for `K`. **So I consider this a bug**. I can’t preclude that there’s a statement somewhere in the depth of the specification which allows to conclude that a compiler should behave that way, but if so, the specification should be fixed as well.

As said by others in the comments section, this code can be compiled with Eclipse without problems.

Answer (score -2):

If we explicitly mention type instead of using diamond operator then it compiles successfully. Following is code for the same:

```
private static final Map<SomeEnum, String> TEST = new EnumMap<SomeEnum, String>(
            Arrays.stream(SomeEnum.values())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t, a -> "")));
```

For the reference that as per another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134626/when-does-diamond-syntax-not-work-in-java-8), in some scenarios, diamond operator is not supported. It could be further dig down if code snippet in question here lands in this bucket.

Comment: It is pretty obvious that the error `cannot infer type arguments` will go away the moment that we explicitly provide the type arguments. The question is why the compiler cannot infer the type arguments in this very specific case.